# Make a Triangularity program valid

Tags: code-golf, string

[Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity) is a new esolang developed by [Mr. Xcoder](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59487/mr-xcoder) where code structure has to follow a very specific pattern:

- For the `n`th line of code, there must be exactly `2n-1` characters of the program on  it.  This causes a triangular/pyramid shape, with the first line having only one character and the rest increasing by increments of 2.
- Each line must be padded with `.`s on the left and right, such that the characters are centered on their lines and all lines are padded to the same length. If `l` is defined as the number of lines in the program, each line in the program must have a length of `2 * l - 1`

For example, the program on the left is valid, but the program on the right isn't:

```
 Valid    |  Invalid  
          |
...A...   |  ABCDE
..BCD..   |  FGH
.EFGHI.   |  IJKLMN
JKLMNOP   |  OPQRS
```

When laid out in the valid structure, the name becomes obvious.

### Task

Your task is to take a single line string as input, representing Triangularity code, and output it converted into valid code as described above.

Specifications for I/O:

- The input will only contain characters in the range `0x20 - 0x7e`
- The length of the input always will be a square number and thus paddable nicely.
- You must use dots for the output padding, not something else.

You may input and output through any [acceptable](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447/66833) method. This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so the shortest code in *bytes* wins!

### Test cases

```
input
----
output

g
----
g

PcSa
----
.P.
cSa

DfJ0vCq7G
----
..D..
.fJ0.
vCq7G

7xsB8a1Oqw5fhHX0
----
...7...
..xsB..
.8a1Oq.
w5fhHX0

QNYATbkX2sKZ6IuOmofwhgaef
----
....Q....
...NYA...
..TbkX2..
.sKZ6IuO.
mofwhgaef

ABCDEF"$%& G8"F@
----
...A...
..BCD..
.EF"$%.
& G8"F@

ab.c
----
.a.
b.c
```

<sub>For those who know Triangularity, you'll notice from the last test case that strings don't have to be handled</sub>

Comment: [Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14548/66833)

Comment: I realise this is probably futile, but would the downvoter care to explain their vote? I'd love to improve the challenge in anyway I can.

Comment: Are leading or trailing newlines acceptable?

Comment: @Arnauld Yes, leading and trailing white space is perfectly fine.

Comment: Is a list of lines fine?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Yes, a list of lines is fine.

Answer (score 20):

## [Triangularity](https://github.com/Mr-Xcoder/Triangularity), 127 bytes

```
.......).......
......2)1......
...../)IL^.....
....f)rMD@_....
...)2)1/)IL^...
..f+`"'.'*"+E..
.DWReD)2s^)Its.
D+@sh+s+})10cJ.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KynKTMxLL81JLMosqfz/Xw8CNKE0F4Qy0jRE5utrevrEIfhpmkW@Lg7xML4mUDVMBZCfpp2gpK6nrqWk7Qriu4QHpbpoGhXHaXqWFOtxuWg7FGdoF2vXahoaJHvp/f8f6BfpGJKUHWFU7B1l5lnqn5ufVp6RnpiaBgA)

### Explanation

Removing the characters that make up for the padding, we get the following program:

```
)2)1/)IL^f)rMD@_)2)1/)IL^f+`"'.'*"+EDWReD)2s^)ItsD+@sh+s+})10cJ
```

... Which is quite length-ish, right? Let's break it down into pieces.

**Generating the integers [0 … √len(input))**

```
)2)1/)IL^f)r – Subprogram #1.
)            – Creates a new stack entry, equal to 0. This must precede any integer
               literal, because each character in '0123456789' isn't parsed on its
               own as a literal, but rather they are commands which multiply the ToS
               by 10 and add the value of their digit equivalent. 
 2           – ToS * 10 + 2 = 2.           || STACK: [2]
  )1         – The literal 1.              || STACK: [2, 1]
    /        – Division.                   || STACK: [1 / 2] = [0.5]
     )I      – Get the input at index 0.   || STACK: [0.5, input]
       L     – Length.                     || STACK: [0.5, len(input)]
        ^    – Exponentiation.             || STACK: [len(input) ** 0.5]
         f   – Trim decimals.              || STACK: [int(len(input) ** 0.5)] 
          )r – Create the list [0 .. ToS). || STACK: [[0 ... int(len(input) ** 0.5))]
```

**Generating the dots**

```
MD@_)2)1/)IL^f+`"'.'*"+E – Subprogram #2.
MD                       – For each integer in the range, run some code on a separate
                           stack, preinitialised to two copies of the argument.
  @_                     – Increment and negate the ToS.
    )2)1/)IL^f           – The square root of the length of the input, again.
              +          – Add the two.
               `         – And cast the integer given to a string.
                "'.'*"+  – Prepends the literal "'.'*" to the string representation.
                       E – Evaluate as a Python expression (basically string repetition).
```

**Trimming the characters at the front**

```
DWReD)2s^)It – Subprogram #3.
D            – Duplicate the result of the expression above.
 W           – Wrap the whole intermediate stack to an array.
  Re         – Reverse the stack and dump the contents separately onto the stack.
    D        – Duplicate the result.
     )2      – Push the literal 2.
       s^    – Swap and perform exponentiation.
         )It – Push the input and trim the characters before that index.
```

**Trimming the characters at the end**

```
sD+@sh+s+ – Subprogram #4.
s         – Swap the top two elements on the stack.
 D+       – Double. Push twice and add.
   @      – Increment.
    sh    – Swap the top two elements and trim the characters after that index.
      +   – Append the first set of dots.
       s+ – And prepend the second set of dots.
```

**Ending the loop and pretty-printing**

```
})10cJ – Subprogram #5.
}      – End the loop.
 )10   – Push the literal 10.
    c  – Convert from code-point to character (yields '\n').
     J – And join the result by newlines.
```

Comment: do you have to score bytes for the "." characters if they are mandated by the intrinsics of the language?

Comment: @JDL Yes, the program cannot run correctly without them, so I must include them in the byte count :-)

Comment: Do you need to "trim decimals", seeing as the length of the input is guaranteed to be square? You should also be able to get rod of the `J` at the end and output an array of lines. Don't know if that's going to save you anything, though, if the end of the last line needs to be padded with `.` to fill the remaining space.

Comment: @Shaggy 1) Yes, `f` is needed because range cannot accept float arguments (even with `.0`) 2) Getting rid of `J` doesn’t save any bytes due to the padding, so I chose the prettier output format.

Answer (score 8):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>15</s> <s>14</s> 10 bytes

Outputs an array of lines.

```
ò@°T¬v1Ãû.
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=8kCwVKx2McP7Lg==&input=IlFOWUFUYmtYMnNLWjZJdU9tb2Z3aGdhZWYiCi1S) | [Check all test cases](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=o1Q9MCxYIPJAsFSsdjHD+y4gtytS&input=WyJnIiwiUGNTYSIsIkRmSjB2Q3E3RyIsIjd4c0I4YTFPcXc1ZmhIWDAiLCJRTllBVGJrWDJzS1o2SXVPbW9md2hnYWVmIiwnQUJDREVGIiQlJiBHOCJGQCcsImFiLmMiXQotUg==)

---

### Explantion

```
ò@     Ã       :Partition at characters where the following function returns true
  °T           :  Increment T (initially 0)
    ¬          :  Square root
     v1        :  Divisible by 1?
               :(Or, in other words, split after every character with a 1-based index that's a perfect square)
        û.     :Centre pad each element with .s to the length of the longest element
```

---

### Original Solution

```
Ê¬ÆsTT±X+°XÃû.
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=yqzGc1RUsVgrsFjD+y4=&input=IlFOWUFUYmtYMnNLWjZJdU9tb2Z3aGdhZWYiCi1S)

```
Ê                  :Length of input
 ¬                 :Square root
  Æ        Ã       :Range [0,Ê¬) and pass each X through a function
   s               :  Slice input
    T              :    from index T, initially 0
     T±X+°X        :    to index T incremented by X plus X incremented
            û.     :Centre pad each element with .s to the length of the longest element
```

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>20</s> <s>19</s> 18 bytes

Saved a byte thanks to *Magic Octopus Urn*

```
ā·<£õKRvy'.N×.ø}r»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATMAzP8wNWFiMWX//8SBwrc8wqPDtUtSdnknLk7Dly7DuH1ywrv//0FCQ0RFRiIkJSYgRzgiRkA)

**Explanation**

```
ā                    # push the list [1 ... len(input)]
 ·<                  # multiply each by 2 and decrement each, making a list of odd numbers
   £                 # split the input into chunks of these sizes
    õK               # remove empty strings
      R              # reverse list
       vy      }     # for each y in the list
             .ø      # surround it with
         '.N×        # "." (dot) repeated N times, where N is the current iteration index
                r    # reverse the stack
                 »   # join stack by newlines
```

Comment: `ÅÉ` for odds may help?

Comment: Something like, `g;ÅÉ£Rvy'.N×.ø}r»`? But not that because that's not right lol.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: `ÅÉ` would definitely help if we could find out the length of the bottom row in 2 bytes. I don't know if we can though. Might be another way to incorporate it as well.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: I had this same solution earlier except I used `)R` instead of `r` which didn't save any bytes :/

Comment: I was trying to find a way to "reverse the loop" to just print as it occurs, no ideas on that though.

Answer (score 7):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 15 bytes

```
Ṡzö`JR2tR'.ṡCİ1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HOBVWHtyV4BRmVBKnrPdy50PnIBsP///8rZaRXVOXnZOfnlGSAoRIA)

### Explanation

```
Ṡzö`JR2tR'.ṡCİ1  Implicit input, say s = "DfJ0vCq7G".
             İ1  List of odd positive integers: [1,3,5,7,..
            C    Cut s to those lengths: x = ["D","fJ0","vCq7G"]
           ṡ     Reversed indices of x: y = [3,2,1]
Ṡz               Zip x and y using this function:
                  Arguments are a string and a number, e.g. r = "fJ0" and n = 2.
        R'.       n copies of '.': ".."
       t          Drop first element: "."
     R2           Two copies of this: [".","."]
  ö`J             Join by r: ".fJ0."
                 Result is ["..D..",".fJ0.","vCq7G"]; implicitly print on separate lines.
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 83 bytes

```python
i=input();u=int(len(i)**.5)
for t in range(u):g="."*(u+~t);print g+i[t*t:][:t-~t]+g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9M2M6@gtERD07oUyCrRyEnN08jU1NLSM9XkSssvUihRyMxTKErMS0/VKNW0SrdV0lPS0ijVrivRtC4oAmpQSNfOjC7RKrGKjbYq0a0ridVO//9fKdAv0jEkKTvCqNg7ysyz1D83P608Iz0xNU0JAA)

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>82</s> 78 bytes

```js
f=(s,k=1-s.length**.5*2,p='')=>s&&f(s.slice(0,k),k+2,p+'.')+`
`+p+s.slice(k)+p
```

#### Test cases

```js
f=(s,k=1-s.length**.5*2,p='')=>s&&f(s.slice(0,k),k+2,p+'.')+`
`+p+s.slice(k)+p

console.log(f('g'))
console.log(f('PcSa'))
console.log(f('DfJ0vCq7G'))
console.log(f('7xsB8a1Oqw5fhHX0'))
console.log(f('QNYATbkX2sKZ6IuOmofwhgaef'))
console.log(f('ABCDEF"$%& G8"F@'))
```

#### Commented

```js
f = (                       // f = recursive function taking:
  s,                        //   s = input string
  k = 1 - s.length**.5 * 2, //   k = additive inverse of the length of the base
  p = ''                    //   p = padding string
) =>                        //
  s &&                      // if s is not empty:
    f(                      //   do a recursive call with:
      s.slice(0, k),        //     s without the last -k characters
      k + 2,                //     the updated base length (2 less characters)
      p + '.'               //     the updated padding string
    ) +                     //   end of recursive call()
    `\n` +                  //   append a line feed
    p +                     //   append the left padding string
    s.slice(k) +            //   append the last -k characters of s
    p                       //   append the right padding string
```

Comment: [minor] the '/n' symbol became an actual line break in the code block at the top - consider escaping it for clarity :)

Comment: @G0BLiN This is the other way around: this _is_ indeed a literal line break in the golfed code, which was replaced with an escaped line break in the ungolfed version for clarity. :)

Comment: Ha, joke's on me, then... :-)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly),  <s>22</s>  19 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
J²‘Ṭœṗ⁸Ṛz”.Zµṙ"JC$Ṛ
```

A monadic link returning a list of lists of characters (the lines)

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AT4Awf9qZWxsef//SsKy4oCY4bmsxZPhuZfigbjhuZp64oCdLlrCteG5mSJKQyThuZr/w4dZ//8iRGZKMHZDcTdHIg)**

#### How?

```
J²‘Ṭœṗ⁸Ṛz”.Zµṙ"JC$Ṛ - Link: list of characters e.g. "DfJ0vCq7G"
J                   - range of length               [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
 ²                  - square (vectorises)           [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64,81]
  ‘                 - increment                     [2,5,10,17,26,37,50,65,82]
   Ṭ                - untruth (1s at those indices) [0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,...]
      ⁸             - chain's left argument         "DfJ0vCq7G"
    œṗ              - partition at indexes          ["D","fJ0","vCq7G"]
       Ṛ            - reverse                       ["vCq7G","fJ0","D"]
         ”.         - literal '.'                   '.'
        z           - transpose with filler         ["vfD","CJ.","q0.","7..","G.."]
           Z        - transpose                     ["vCq7G","fJ0..","D...."]
            µ       - start a new monadic chain
                 $  - last two links as a monad:
               J    -   range of length             [1,2,3]
                C   -   complement (vectorises)     [0,-1,-2]
              "     - zip with:
             ṙ      -   rotate left by              ["vCq7G",".fJ0.","..D.."]
                  Ṛ - reverse                       ["..D..",".fJ0.","vCq7G"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 21 bytes

```
tnX^eRP&1ZvGyg(46y~(!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/vyQvIi41KEDNMKrMvTJdw8Sssk5D8f9/dUcnZxdXNyUVVTUFdwslNwd1AA)

#### Explanation

Consider input `'DfJ0vCq7G'` as an example. The stack contents are shown separated by commas, with the top element last. Rows in a 2D array use semicolon as separator.

```
t      % Implicit input: string. Duplicate
       % STACK: 'DfJ0vCq7G',
                'DfJ0vCq7G'
nX^    % Number of elements. Square root
       % STACK: 'DfJ0vCq7G',
                3
e      % Reshape with that many rows (in column major order)
       % STACK: ['D0q';
                 'fv7';
                 'JCG']
R      % Upper triangular part: set elements below diagonal to char(0)
       % (displayed as space)
       % STACK: ['D0q';
                 ' v7';
                 '  G']
P      % Flip vertically
       % STACK: ['  G';
                 ' v7';
                 'D0q']
&1Zv   % Reflect vertically
       % STACK: ['  G';
                 ' v7';
                 'D0q';
                 ' v7';
                 '  G']
G      % Push input again
       % STACK: ['  G';
                 ' v7';
                 'D0q';
                 ' v7';
                 '  G'],
                'DfJ0vCq7G'
yg     % Duplicate from below and convert to logical. This gives true for
       % for nonzero chars (the entries where input chars will be written)
       % STACK: ['  G';
                 ' v7';
                 'D0q';
                 ' v7';
                 '  G'],
                'DfJ0vCq7G',
                [0 0 1;
                 0 1 1;
                 1 1 1;
                 0 1 1;
                 0 0 1]
(      % Assignment indexing: write values at those positions
       % STACK: ['  v';
                 ' fC';
                 'DJq';
                 ' 07';
                 '  G']
46     % Push 46, which is ASCII for '.'
       % STACK: ['  v';
                 ' fC';
                 'DJq';
                 ' 07';
                 '  G'],
                 46
y~     % Duplicate from below and apply logical negate. This gives true
       % for char(0) (the entries where '.' will be written)
       % STACK: ['  G';
                 ' v7';
                 'D0q';
                 ' v7';
                 '  G'],
                46
                [1 1 0;
                 1 0 0;
                 0 0 0;
                 1 0 0;
                 1 1 0]
(      % Assignment indexing: write value at those positions
       % STACK: ['..G';
                 '.v7';
                 'D0q';
                 '.v7';
                 '..G'],
!      % Transpose. Implicit display
       % STACK: ['..D..';
                 '.fJ0.';
                 'vCq7G']
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 25 bytes

```
gÅÉ£õKð'ø‡.c¶¡ζøð'.‡'øð‡»
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8//XDr4c5Diw9v9T68Qf3wjkcNC/WSD207tPDctsM7gCJ6QAF1EAtIH9r9/7@jk7OLq5uSiqqagruFkpsDAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>107</s> <s>94</s> <s>89</s> 88 bytes

```
import StdEnv
@s _[]=s
@s n r= @([['.':l]++['.']\\l<-s]++[take n r])(n+2)(drop n r)
```

```
@[]1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYxPC8IgHEDvfYofo9IxFtQpokF/tkXQbUcnQ6bGSN1QC/ryWXZ7Dx6vV4KZoEf@VAI0G0wY9DRaD43nlXnNJDjoCC3cnwzYQmJC0ArtFM2yCLRt1T530Tx7iNjQFJtsk2Juxyl6GhrPfs8CJKFrIOh4OpdVncwXS7hsk/qAaPj0UrG7C/n1Fsq3YXro3Rc) Example usage: `@[]1 ['ABCDEF"$%& G8"F@']`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), <strike>227</strike> 203 bytes

```
f: func[s][l: to-integer(length? s)** 0.5
n: 0 foreach m parse s[collect[(r: []repeat i l[append r reduce['keep i * 2 - 1
charset[not{Я}]]])r]][v: copy""insert/dup v"."l - n: n + 1 print rejoin[v m v]]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY6xTsMwGAb3PMUnL22DWtpKMGRBjAgJBGIALA@p/TtJ69rWbycIIZ6JV@GNgplPdzomMz@TgVSzbWBHr2VS0jXIYT34TB3x0pHvcn@DtKprbDdXlW@whQ1Mre5xRmw5EZLUwTnSWS65KT2mSG3GACfbGMkbMJjMqEkuTkSxkBp7rLGrdP9fyNKH/PX7862UWrFScmqgQ/wUYvCJOF@aMWISG@GKVBY8LrBD5LJZwscweDmVm6nos4V4eni7fTmcXvfp/v36bnw8B/vRdy1ZUc1/)

Ungolfed:

```
f: func[s][
l: to-integer (length? s) ** 0.5
n: 0
foreach m parse s [ 
    collect [
        (r: []
        repeat i l [ append r reduce [
            'keep i * 2 - 1 charset [ not{Я} ]]])
    r ]] 
    [v: copy ""
    insert/dup v "." l - n: n + 1
    print rejoin [v m v]]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>84</s> 68 bytes

```hs
[]%1
(s%n)[]=s
(s%n)r=(['.':l++"."|l<-s]++[take n r])%(n+2)$drop n r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcldT8IwGIbhc3/Fm4bJlsoCJAoxLpEPAUVFgwdo14OXuW5kXSnrBh742602nt3P9eRoilRKm0WxZdzrnfnGUwHjkfmvKvJZO2xfS0pJSL7lTcdwSlmNRQoKKh54vqL9oPVZ7bUDW@JOQQQl6ifwdVOv6@pRQQiNkjuVmr/KAmDkJVkjuQAyFQ/d4@QwmLsx@DLjIfZWh9OlyBebrrPX5/fR27bY9M3y4@q@WZV7ccozTIU7R@PJ9G4Wk5Z3DvNhTGa3TnEbJoTbn0RIzIztJFr/Ag)

Example usage: `[]%1 $ "abcd"` yields the list of lines `[".a.","bcd"]`.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, <s>56</s> 52 bytes

Includes `+3` for `-p`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
$_=("."x y///c**.5)=~s%.%$'@{[$&x/$`$`./g]}$'
%rg
```

Give input on STDIN (in principle without final newline, but that only matters for the empty input)

Comment: according to PCG rules `-p` costs only 1 byte

Comment: @mik Only if the code doesn't contain `'`. But this code does, so it needs to be put in a file (or escaping on the commandline) which needs 3 extra characters compared to the normal `#!` line. So in this case it is `+3` (for normal code you will see I indeed only count `+` for `p`)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
ＵＢ.Ｆ₂Ｌθ«Ｐ✂θＸι²Ｘ⊕ι²↙
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYw9D4IwFABn@BWE6TVBBwYHnTQuRPALB3Wr5QENpU9qgcH42ysOjneXnKi5EcSVcznaDRdNZajXBYTzkK38kkwAeddzg2ciCynqytbQMcaCt@9lvbLyaaS2kCspELooONKIBmQUxOwPiRYGW9QWC5DsV9j09jIaEJZbGnWKpZ3Mx7nT/ra@PJpr/NrdF0l/aKkc64pj6WaD@gI) Link is to verbose version of code. Edit: Saved 2 bytes by discovering `SquareRoot`. Explanation:

```
ＵＢ.                 Set the background fill to `.`
      θ             (First) input
     Ｌ              Length
    ₂               Square root
   Ｆ   «            Loop over implicit range
            ι   ι   Current value
               ⊕    Incremented
             ²   ²  Literal 2
           Ｘ  Ｘ     Power
         ✂θ         Slice the (first) input string
        Ｐ           Print without moving the cursor
                  ↙ Move down left
```

Comment: :/ [This](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z84tcQpMTk7vSi/NC9FQ0lPSdOaKyA/pzI9P08j2iq0ICgzPaNER8HKJb88D8yO1VEILixNLEoNys8v0fBJzUsvydAo1NTUUagEanXLzMkB8qz//w/0i3QMScqOMCr2jjLzLPXPzU8rz0hPTE37r1uWAwA) almost works but it appears Charcoal is a bit buggy. [This](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z84tcQpMTk7vSi/NC9FQ0lPSdOaKyA/pzI9P0/DykZHIbiwNLEoNSg/v0TDJzUvvSRDo1BTU0dBS6NSR8FIE6jYLTMnByhm/f9/oF@kY0hSdoRRsXeUmWepf25@WnlGemJq2n/dshwA) works though, I think?

Comment: @ASCII-only ... what black magic is this?

Comment: Fill basically checks for null bytes (i.e. the character used for space where nothing is drawn), so you can just draw a polygon with null bytes (well, if it even works correctly >_>) and fill that. Obviously this isn't exactly intended since you can actually see the null bytes even before the fill for some reason >_>

Comment: [this](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z84tcQpMTk7vSi/NC9FQ0lPSdOaKyA/pzI9P0/DykZHIbiwNLEoNSg/v0TDJzUvvSRDo1BTU0ehEqjMLTMnB8iz/v8/0C/SMSQpO8Ko2DvKzLPUPzc/rTwjPTE17b9uWQ4A) should work properly next pull

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language), <s>88</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```
S1`
+m`^(.)+¶(?>(?<-1>.)+)..(?!¶)
$&¶
P^'.m`^.(?=(..)*)(?<-1>.)*
P'.`.+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxLNPz/P9gwgUs7NyFOQ09T@9A2DXs7DXsbXUM7IE9TT0/DXvHQNk0uFbVD27gC4tT1gOqAYrYaenqaWpowhVpcAep6CXra//8H@kU6hiRlRxgVe0eZeZb65@anlWekJ6amAQA) Edit: Saved <s>12</s> 13 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder. Explanation:

```
S1`
```

Split first character into its own line to get the ball rolling.

```
+m`^(.)+¶(?>(?<-1>.)+)..(?!¶)
$&¶
```

Chop each line two characters longer than the previous one.

```
P^'.m`^.(?=(..)*)(?<-1>.)*
```

Left-pad the first half of each line, effectively centring them.

```
P'.`.+
```

Right-pad all of the lines.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 84 bytes

```python
s=input()
l=int(len(s)**.5)
for i in range(l):print s[i*i:][:i-~i].center(l*2-1,'.')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcqxDoMgEADQ3a9g445UorS2lcQvUQfTYHsJOQnQwaW/Tk3c3vDCnj8bm7IOU0kDcfhmwMofyuAdQ0KldIfVukVBgljEhd8OPNoQjyPSSIrsPFqqfzTrl@PsInhl6vYitcRSZGuut@7@ePbNKfkH)

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), 123 bytes

```
import StdEnv
?n l#(a,b)=splitAt n l
|b>[]=[a: ?(n+2)b]=[a]
$s#s= ?1s
=[c++l++c\\l<-s&i<-[1..],c<-[repeatn(length s-i)'.']]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY1PC4IwHEDvfoofaqlMhTpFuOyvEXTruHaYc9lgLnErCPrsLbu99y6PK8G06x7NUwnomNROdv1jsHCxzUG/vFKDCmKW1gk2vZJ2Y2Es3qdeEYoJW0IZazRP6r9QLzSBwVDOjIcJR0ghxK9XVWRmKouMzPKcpnyEQfSCWR0roVt7B5PJJMojSt3FsnGNISTRZrvbHyo/nEzhuPCrdUTdl98Ua43LTme3f2vWSW5@)

Comment: Some friendly [competition](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154882/56433).

Comment: @Laikoni Ooh, that's my favourite kind of competition!

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>73</s> 66 bytes

```ruby
->s{(1..z=s.size**0.5).map{|q|s[q*q-2*q+1...q*q].center 2*z-1,?.}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5NT8JAGITv@yvebNToSjdtE4RLVT4ElEQ0ekBLY7bLLiWGwvK2IqX89lqpxNPMMzOHWafhttBeYV3j7tzhPPOQ4zxTjNm8fsEXYrXLTY6@YcZymbksJ7z0AZcqTtQaXJZZTu2G7/dFojD5kAIVggc@AaAzWvuVJ/kiKtfVD/ZXxzT6FTa@sd0Uzshs6joajO0qfX58a72Gn2MXh@9X9@losdSbaCaUrupWu9O9603oyekZ9JsT2rutchFySUlAyP8ProSMYLqEfB6v0iQvZ6UgHOgI1KLAwLGPrP1DHfwxUfG0@AE)

-5 bytes: Return an array of strings instead of printing them

-2 bytes: Declare `z` in place instead of ahead of time

Ungolfed:

```ruby
->s{
  (1..z=s.size**0.5).map{|q|   # Map the range [1,sqrt(s.size)]
    s[q*q-2*q+1...q*q]         # To the relevant portion of s,
      .center 2*z-1, ?.        #   padded left and right with . characters
  }
}
```

Declaring a variable `r=q-1` so that I can take `s[r*r...q*q]` saves exactly zero bytes.

Using `.center` instead of padding manually also saves zero bytes, but I like it better.

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 19 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
╚└÷2╬#►o┴X≡¥ΩåV∙¬?♥
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=c8c0f632ce23106fc158f09dea8656f9aa3f03&i=DfJ0vCq7G%0AABCDEF%22%24%25%26+G8%22F%40&m=2)

ASCII equivalent:

```
z;%|q{Hv,:/~]+F|Cm0]'.R
```